# Why The Include is not working here?

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code works fine if i explicitly add the HTML i want using `echo`, but i wanted to make the code more clean by including the markup file, which is in the same directory of the including script, but for some reason it won't include. Here is the code:

```
function render_social_links() {
$current_post_id=get_the_ID();
$them_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
$featured_image_url = '';
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $current_post_id ) ) {
    $featured_image_id  = get_post_thumbnail_id( $current_post_id );
    $featured_image_url = $featured_image_id ? wp_get_attachment_url( $featured_image_id ) : '';
}
if(is_home() || is_single()){
      if(is_home()){
        $bitlink = $lnk = get_bloginfo('url');
        $bitly = getBitly($bitlink);
        $nam = get_bloginfo('name');
        }
        elseif(is_single($current_post_id)){
            $bitlink = $lnk = get_permalink($current_post_id);
            $bitly = getBitly($bitlink);
            $nam = get_the_title($current_post_id);
        }

        include( __DIR__ . '/social-links.php' );
      }

  }
```

And this is the markup inside the social-links.php, and this file is in a child theme and is included in the child's functions.php

```
<div id="socialleft">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/share-38.png" alt=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$lnk.'&amp;t='.$nam.'" title="شارك على فيسبوك" target="_blank">
                </li>
                        <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/facebook-38.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status='.$nam.' : '.$bitly.'" title="غرد" target="_blank">
                        <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/twitter-38.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$lnk.'" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
                      \'\', \'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600\');return false;" title="شارك على جوجل+" target="_blank">
                        <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/Google-plus-38.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the content of `social-links.php` or a similar content? And it is given some warning or error?

Comment: If I used the contents of `social-links.php` directly without including it works excellent. but when including nothing outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your `social-links.php`.

Accoding to the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end tags.

If you `social-links.php` only contains HTML this will be parsed as HTML.

I make a simple test and worked.

teste.php

```
<?php

function teste_include()
{
    include 'teste_include.php';
}

teste_include();
```

and teste_included.php

```
<div>teste 2</div><br><div>teste 3</div>
```

Comment: My `social-links.php` contains both php and html. I have edited my question with adding its contents

Comment: Thanks man the problem solved. i enclosed it in PHP tags and it worked

Answer (score 0):

i don't know where is your social-links.php

suppose your social-links.php in your custom theme directory then use given below code to include your social-links.php

```
 include(get_template_directory_uri(). '/social-links.php' );
```